# pygame.image.load not working

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a world map for a game, but when I try to load the world map to the screen, the command line tells me I'm unable to do so. Here is the code:

```
import sys 
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * 
pygame.init ()

Surface = pygame.display.set_mode ((1000, 775), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('World Map')

WorldMap = pygame.image.load('WorldMap.jpg')
white = (255, 255, 255)
while True:
    Surface.fill (white)
    Surface.blit (WorldMap, (900, 675))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit ()
            sys.exit (0)
    pygame.display.update()
```

The error looks something like this ----

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "C:\Users\The Folder\WorldMap.py", line 9, in <module> 
    WorldMap = pygame.image.load ('WorldMap.jpg')
  pygame.error: Couldn't open WorldMap.jpg
```

Comment: note: the spaces before function parenthesis should be removed. ex: `pygame.init ()` to `pygame.init()` , same with `fill`, `blit`, etc...

Comment: is that specific syntax really necessary, I thought the Python compiler disregarded spaces between function signatures and parameters/arguments

Answer (score 5):

The error message is pretty clear: pygame can't find your image in the place you said it would be.

You have to make sure that the image `WorldMap.jpg` exists in your **current working directory** (CWD).

If you double-click your .py file, the CWD is the directory containing the .py. So `WorldMap.jpg` must be there. If you execute it from the command line from a different directory, add code for that or put the image in the other directory.

Comment: Yes, the image does exist in the program's CWD, I actually created a new directory just for both the image and the program, and the same error keeps coming up. The file size of the image is 652 KB, would that have something to do with the error. (Does pygame.image.load have a "loading" capacity?)

Comment: verify `C:\Users\The Folder\WorldMap.jpg` is the exact spelling and filepath to your image.

Comment: @monkey It is, however is it possible that I can place the whole path as the argument to the pygame.image.load function (e.g. WorldMap = pygame.image.load('C:\Users\The Folder\WorldMap.jpg')?

Comment: @user1452509: yes. You'll have to escape the backslashes though: `pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\The Folder\\WorldMap.jpg')`

Comment: Or `os.path.join("c:", "Users", "The Folder", "WorldMap.jpg")` this creates cross platform path separators. That one won't be (because "c:\" as a root is only windows), but, if you use paths relative project root, it will be.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem. I started my .py not from the working directory of the pogram. After I used cd to get to the right directory all was fine. So first make sure to get your current working directory the same as the working directory and start your program.